# C++ compile-time type comparsion

Tags: c++

Consider the function `foo`.

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    do_something();
    if (T == int) {
        do_somehting_else();
    }
}
```

In other words, I want it to `do_something()` and then, if the type is `int`, `do_something_else()`

Of course `if (T == int) {` won't compile. Still: is there any way to compare types in compile-time in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    do_something();
    if (std::is_same<T,int>::value) {
        do_somehting_else();
    }
}
```

You can learn more about type traits [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

Comment: This only works if the conditional code is valid whatever the type. Otherwise, you'll want to wrap it in another template, specialised for `int`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yep, but OP's example does not do that. He will eventually find out and explore other options, but learning type traits is generally useful and the base for so many other things... :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use a template specialization.

```
template <typename T> void foo() { do_something(); }

template<> void foo<int>() { do_something(); do_something_else(); };
```